# How can I run redemo.py (or equivalent) on a Mac?

Tags: python, regex

In the Python installation on my PC there is a sweet script in C:\python26\tools\scripts called `redemo.py`. It's a simple tk application for testing regular expressions.

I wish I could get it--or something like it--running on my Mac, but I don't know how. The script doesn't appear to be part of the Python installation on my Mac. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view the script directly from the python svn repository [here](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Tools/scripts/) and can download it:

```
curl http://svn.python.org/view/*checkout*/python/trunk/Tools/scripts/redemo.py?content-type=text%2Fplain > redemo.py
/usr/bin/python redemo.py
```

It seems to work just fine as is on OS X 10.6 with python 2.6.

Comment: Beh, I should have been able to figure this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, we should check whether the `redemo.py` is included in our system by using:

```
find / -name redemo.py # you can change the root searching path from `/` to other folder if you know the more specific path where python is installed.
```

Because some python distribution provider (e.g. Anaconda or default python in Linux/Unix distr.) sometimes will exclude this demo tool when install the python in our system.

---

If we found the `redemo.py` file within some python environments (assuming we have more than one python installed) then we can run it directly:

```
/right/path/python /right/path/redemo.py
```

But if there is no `redemo.py` file found in our system, we can still download this demo tool from official code repo (now at [GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython)) and play with it.

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python/cpython/3.6/Tools/demo/redemo.py > redemo.py
python redemo.py # Note the version is 3.6 in download path.
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Python on your Mac, then copy the script over? It should work fine on any Python installation.

Comment: Python should already be installed on Mac OS X.  At least it is on mine, but then again I installed the developer tools.

Comment: Yes, it is a standard component on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X comes with Python pre-installed.  As of 10.6.2 it has Python 2.6.1 found at `/usr/bin/python`.  Copy redemo.py to your Mac.  Make sure you have X11.app running and open a terminal (Terminal.app is available by default) and just run:

```
% python /path/to/redemo.py
```

Assuming there aren't any Win32 specific hooks in this script, it should execute.

Comment: The Tk and Pythons on modern OS X versions don't use X11.  The script will run just fine with the standard Aqua Tk.

Answer (score 0):

Python is part of OS X, but sometimes it's a bit out of date: http://www.python.org/download/mac/

Comment: That script directory is not included in the OS X Python installer installations.